# Differences between LM555CN-R and LM555CN/NOPB

Tags: integrated-circuit, 555

I am trying to buy a LM555CN-R online, however I can only find an LM555CN/NOPB. What are the differences, if any, on these chips?

Comment: Which vendor? TI doesn't list an LM555CN-R in their datasheet

Comment: I always thought that NOPB meant "no lead [on the device pins]" and was part of ROHS

Answer (score 1):

The LM555CN-R is made by fairchild semiconductor
[Datasheet](https://datasheet.octopart.com/LM555CN-ON-Semiconductor-datasheet-85572618.pdf)

The LM555CN/NOPB is made by Texas instruments
[Datasheet](https://datasheet.octopart.com/LM555CN-NOPB-Texas-Instruments-datasheet-39144970.pdf)

The subtle difference is found in the datasheets e.g. power dissipation capabilities.